# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method?

Tags: java, android

Im trying to screenshot the live stream of my ip cam. I am able to do it and save it to my sd card the problem is im getting an ("Unfortunately your Apps has stopped") after clicking the screenshot button. This is my code...

```
    package com.example.isec.isec;



    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Random;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
    import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
    import android.graphics.Rect;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
    import android.view.SurfaceView;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

public class MjpegView extends SurfaceView implements                              SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private static final String TAG = "MjpegView";

public final static int POSITION_UPPER_LEFT = 9;
public final static int POSITION_UPPER_RIGHT = 3;
public final static int POSITION_LOWER_LEFT = 12;
public final static int POSITION_LOWER_RIGHT = 6;
public final static int SIZE_STANDARD = 1;
public final static int SIZE_BEST_FIT = 4;
public final static int SIZE_FULLSCREEN = 8;

//private MjpegViewfunc clickFunc;
private MjpegViewThread thread;
private MjpegInputStream mIn = null;
private boolean showFps = false;
private boolean mRun = false;
private boolean surfaceDone = false;
private Paint overlayPaint;
private int overlayTextColor;
private int overlayBackgroundColor;
private int ovlPos;
private int dispWidth;
private int dispHeight;
private int displayMode;


    public void clickFunc(View view) {

        if (view.getId() == R.id.button9) ;
      //  Toast.makeText(MjpegViewfunc.this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        try {
            //Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenShot();
            MjpegView.this.thread.run();
            // Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenShot(activity, ResourceID);
            // saveBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }


    public class MjpegViewThread extends Thread {
        private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
        private int frameCounter = 0;
        private long start;
        private Bitmap ovl;

        public MjpegViewThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context) {
            mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        }

        private Rect destRect(int bmw, int bmh) {
            int tempx;
            int tempy;
            if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_STANDARD) {
                tempx = (dispWidth / 2) - (bmw / 2);
                tempy = (dispHeight / 2) - (bmh / 2);
                return new Rect(tempx, tempy, bmw + tempx, bmh + tempy);
            }
            if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_BEST_FIT) {
                float bmasp = (float) bmw / (float) bmh;
                bmw = dispWidth;
                bmh = (int) (dispWidth / bmasp);
                if (bmh > dispHeight) {
                    bmh = dispHeight;
                    bmw = (int) (dispHeight * bmasp);
                }
                tempx = (dispWidth / 2) - (bmw / 2);
                tempy = (dispHeight / 2) - (bmh / 2);
                return new Rect(tempx, tempy, bmw + tempx, bmh + tempy);
            }
            if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_FULLSCREEN) {
                return new Rect(0, 0, dispWidth, dispHeight);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void setSurfaceSize(int width, int height) {
            synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                dispWidth = width;
                dispHeight = height;
            }
        }


        public Bitmap makeFpsOverlay(Paint p, String text) {
            Rect b = new Rect();
            p.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), b);
            int bwidth = b.width() + 2;
            int bheight = b.height() + 2;
            Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bwidth, bheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
            p.setColor(overlayBackgroundColor);
            c.drawRect(0, 0, bwidth, bheight, p);
            p.setColor(overlayTextColor);
            c.drawText(text, -b.left + 1, (bheight / 2) - ((p.ascent() + p.descent()) / 2) + 1, p);
            return bm;
        }





        public void run() {
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            PorterDuffXfermode mode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER);
            Bitmap bm;
            int width;
            int height;
            Rect destRect;
            Canvas c = null;
            Paint p = new Paint();
            String fps;
            while (mRun) {
                if (surfaceDone) {
                    try {
                        c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                        synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                            try {
                                bm = mIn.readMjpegFrame();
                                destRect = destRect(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight());
                                c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                                c.drawBitmap(bm, null, destRect, p);
                                if (showFps) {
                                    p.setXfermode(mode);
                                    if (ovl != null) {
                                        height = ((ovlPos & 1) == 1) ? destRect.top : destRect.bottom - ovl.getHeight();
                                        width = ((ovlPos & 8) == 8) ? destRect.left : destRect.right - ovl.getWidth();
                                        c.drawBitmap(ovl, width, height, null);
                                    }

                                    //return bm;

                                    p.setXfermode(null);
                                    frameCounter++;
                                    if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) >= 1000) {
                                        fps = String.valueOf(frameCounter) + " fps";
                                        frameCounter = 0;
                                        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                        ovl = makeFpsOverlay(overlayPaint, fps);
                                    }


                                    Random r = new Random();
                                    int iterator = r.nextInt();
                                    String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/screenshots/";
                                    File imageFile = new File(mPath);
                                    imageFile.mkdirs();
                                    imageFile = new File(imageFile + "/" + iterator + "_screenshot.png");
                                    try {
                                        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
                                        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

                                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                                        fos.write(bitmapdata);
                                        fos.flush();
                                        fos.close();
                                        return;
                                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                     return;
                                }

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.getStackTrace();
                                Log.d(TAG, "catch IOException hit in run", e);
                            }
                        }

                    } finally {
                        if (c != null) {
                            mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            //  return;
        }

    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        thread = new MjpegViewThread(holder, context);
        setFocusable(true);
        overlayPaint = new Paint();
        overlayPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        overlayPaint.setTextSize(12);
        overlayPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
        overlayTextColor = Color.WHITE;
        overlayBackgroundColor = Color.BLACK;
        ovlPos = MjpegView.POSITION_LOWER_RIGHT;
        displayMode = MjpegView.SIZE_STANDARD;
        dispWidth = getWidth();
        dispHeight = getHeight();
    }

    public void startPlayback() {
        if (mIn != null) {
            mRun = true;
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    public void stopPlayback() {
        mRun = false;
        boolean retry = true;
        while (retry) {
            try {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAG, "catch IOException hit in stopPlayback", e);
            }
        }
    }

    public MjpegView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int f, int w, int h) {
        thread.setSurfaceSize(w, h);
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        surfaceDone = false;
        stopPlayback();
    }

    public MjpegView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        surfaceDone = true;
    }

    public void showFps(boolean b) {
        showFps = b;
    }

    public void setSource(MjpegInputStream source) {
        mIn = source;
        startPlayback();
    }

    public void setOverlayPaint(Paint p) {
        overlayPaint = p;
    }

    public void setOverlayTextColor(int c) {
        overlayTextColor = c;
    }

    public void setOverlayBackgroundColor(int c) {
        overlayBackgroundColor = c;
    }

    public void setOverlayPosition(int p) {
        ovlPos = p;
    }

    public void setDisplayMode(int s) {
        displayMode = s;
    }
}
```

and my errors ....

```
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        09-09 11:18:47.227  10479-10900/com.example.isec.isec D/dalvikvm﹕                 GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4036K, 22% free 21589K/27336K,               paused 79ms, total 82ms
        09-09 11:18:47.237  10479-10900/com.example.isec.isec W/System.err﹕                                                                                              java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/screenshots/-1867569916_screenshot.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        09-09 11:18:47.237  10479-10900/com.example.isec.isec W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
        09-09 11:18:47.237  10479-10900/com.example.isec.isec W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
        09-09 11:18:47.237  10479-10900/com.example.isec.isec W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
        09-09 11:18:47.247  10479-10900/com.example.isec.isec W/System.err﹕ at com.examp
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the following line in your Android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```